# "missing using directive" pass data from sql database to view asp.net mvc3 c#

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, google-maps, c#-4.0

I have seen codes passing model data to the view but I have not seen anyone pass data from the sql database to the view. I'm trying to pass my data from the sql database to the view so that I can view it on my webpage. I always get an error saying missing using directive.

```
 "CS1061: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'longitude' and no extension method 'longitude' accepting 
 a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"
```

I'm missing something..anyone know?? Thanks.

Here is my code. I'm trying to get the longitude and latitude from my database.

Home Controller Code

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var ldc = new locationDataContext();
        var loc = (from l in ldc.locationModels select l).First();
        return View(loc);
    }
```

Index View Code

```
@model IEnumerable<googleMap2.Models.locationModel>
@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "MVC 3 and Google Maps"; 
}

@section Scripts { 
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
}

@section Styles { 
    html { height: 80% } 
    body { height: 80%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px } 
    #map_canvas { height: 80% } 
}

<h2>Hello, Google Maps</h2>

<div id="map_canvas" style="width:80%; height:80%"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function initialize() {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(@Model.longitude, @Model.latitude);
        var options = { zoom: 14, center: latlng, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), options);
        //google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    }

    $(function () {
        initialize();
    }); 

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your model is of type IEnumerable<>, declared here:

```
@model IEnumerable<googleMap2.Models.locationModel >
```

, yet here:

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(@Model.longit ude, @Model.latitude);
```

You try to reference latitude and longitute properties...

So, either your model should be of type googleMap2.Models.locationModel or you should be enumerating over your model ie

```
foreach(var location in model)
{
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(location.longitude, location.latitude);
// rest of code here 
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work either. I've tried making it `@model googleMap2.Models.location and @model IEnumerable`. I've also tried `foreach (var l in model){...} and var latlng = new google.maps.latlng ...`

Comment: Okay, from looking at your controller method your model is of type googleMap2.Models.locationModel, use this in your view.

Comment: I've tried that already but it doesn't work also. It keeps saying I'm missing a using directive..

Comment: What type is loc? Are there latitude and longitude fields/properties on it?